# is there any way to format an "opened read-only" usb disk

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, gparted, hardware

I am trying to format an "opened read-only" usb drive, but it is failing. tried with gparted and some other tools and utilities like fdisk., etc., but no luck.

Since it is not a noraml "read-only" usb disk, all tools are unable to format the disk.

Requesting for any suggestion to format a usb disk which giving "Opened Read-Only" error. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "*it is not a normal 'read-only' usb disk*?"

Comment: normal  'read-only' means, if the disk is write protected then the disk shows it as "read-only" but in my case it is different. I have not enabled write protection option or by any virus made "read-only". this is something different, don't know the cause of "opened read-only" error

Comment: The most common cause is a damaged filesystem (run `fsck` to repair it). The second most common cause is a faulty (dying) USB stick. They do wear out.

Comment: seems like dying usb stick :(

Comment: GParted will not be able to do anything to the stick if it is mounted. Try unmounting it.